# Cannot set alpha for Tab view in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have created a destination bar with some alpha as background color, so items are slightly visible when I scroll :

```
@Composable
fun DestinationBar(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    title: String,
    navController: NavController? = null,
    type: TMDbType? = null,
    upPress: (() -> Unit)? = null,
) {
    Column(modifier = modifier.statusBarsPadding()) {
        TopAppBar(
            backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.background.copy(alpha = AlphaNearOpaque),
            contentColor = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface,
            elevation = 0.dp
        ) {
            IconButton(
                onClick = { upPress?.invoke() },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .alpha(if (upPress == null) 0f else 1f)
                    .align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
            ) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowBack,
                    contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.back)
                )
            }
```

As you see I used following line for that :

```
backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.background.copy(alpha = AlphaNearOpaque)
```

Now I am trying to use same structure in my Tab view :

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun BookmarkScreen(
    onClickMovie: (TMDbItem) -> Unit,
    onClickTVShow: (TMDbItem) -> Unit,
    coroutineScope: CoroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
) {
    val tabs = remember { MediaTab.values() }
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState(pageCount = {
        tabs.size
    })
    val selectedTabIndex = pagerState.currentPage

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .statusBarsPadding()
    ) {
        TabRow(
            selectedTabIndex = selectedTabIndex,
            divider = { TMDbDivider() }
        ) {
            tabs.forEach { tab ->
                val index = tab.ordinal
                val selected = selectedTabIndex == index
                Tab(
                    selected = selected,
                    onClick = { coroutineScope.launch { pagerState.animateScrollToPage(index) } },
                    text = {
                        Text(
                            text = stringResource(id = tab.titleResourceId),
                            style = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle1
                        )
                    }
                )
            }
        }

        HorizontalPager(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            state = pagerState,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top
        ) { page ->
            when (page) {
                MediaTab.Movies.ordinal -> MoviesTabContent(onClickMovie)
                MediaTab.TvShows.ordinal -> TVShowsTabContent(onClickTVShow)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I set background color for my `TabRow`, alpha does not apply and items will not be visible under tab bar. Why is that? how to resolve it?

Source code can be found here : https://github.com/alirezaeiii/TMDb-Compose-Playground

**Addenda**

I reported this in issue tracker : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/298271482